# Credit Card Checker by Luhm Algorithm on Javascript

Tags: javascript

The goal is to write function which gets an array as a parametr and returns new array by using [Luhm Algorithm](https://codecademy-content.s3.amazonaws.com/PRO/independent-practice-projects/credit-card-checker/diagrams/cc+validator+diagram+1.svg). The function is not finished but I have an issue with new array part. I don't know why but there is not even any errors in console, but just nothing.

```js
const card = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];

function validateCred(arr) {
  let algResult = [];

  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i => 0; i--) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      algResult.push(arr[i]);
    } 
    else if (i % 2 == 0) {
      let nx2 = arr[i] * 2;
      if (nx2 > 9) {
        nx2 -= 9;
        algResult.push(nx2);
        }
      else {
        algResult.push(arr[i]);
        };
    }
  };
  return algResult;
}
console.log(validateCred(card))
```

Comment: There is a typo in your `for` loop. The expression `i => 0` is always truthy, so your `for` loop never stops. Perhaps you meant to write `i >= 0`?

Comment: `i => 0` is a function that always returns 0, which is evaluated as false, so the loop runs once. I believe you mean `i >= 0`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'd just point out that `i => 0` is as you say, it's a function that always returns 0. However the loop as written is using that (truthy) function expression as it's exit condition, so it does not run just once, it runs forever.

Comment: @CRice I stand (well, actually slouch) corrected :).

Comment: `i => 0` surely you mean `i >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

I took a look on Luhm Algorithm that you provided in your question, and I made a function that takes an input card number as string because you will validate input type text value which is string and not a number and it returns true or false (whether it's valid or not).

```js
function isValidCardNumber(cardStrInput) {
  var sum = 0;
  cardStrInput.split("").reverse().forEach(function(digit, ind) {
    var a = Number(digit);
    sum += ind % 2 === 1 ? (a * 2 > 9 ? a * 2 - 9 : a * 2) : a;
  });
  return sum % 10 === 0;
}

console.log(isValidCardNumber("4539689887705798"));
```